# Kubeflow Error in handling large input file: The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage

Tags: kubeflow-pipelines

In Kubeflow - When input file size is really large (60 GB), I am getting 'The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage.' It looks like kubeflow is using /tmp folder to store the files. I had following questions:

- What is the best way to exchange really large files? How to avoid ephemeral-storage issue?
- Will all the InputPath and OutputPath files are stored in MinIO Instance of Kubeflow? If yes, how can we purge the data from MinIO?
- When data is passed between one stage of workflow to the next, does Kubeflow download file from MinIO and copy it to /tmp folder and pass InputPath to the function?
- Is there a better way to pass pandas dataframe between different stages of workflow? Currently I am exporting pandas dataframe as CSV to OutputPath of the operation and reloading pandas dataframe from InputPath in the next stage.
- Is there a way to use different volume for file exchange than using ephemeral storage? If yes, how I can configure it?

```
   import pandas as pd 
   print("text_path:", text_path)
   pd_df = pd.read_csv(text_path)
   print(pd_df)
   with open(text_path, 'r') as reader:
       for line in reader:
           print(line, end = '')
```